# How do I include libphonenumber-js in my angular2 app using systemJS?

Tags: javascript, angular, systemjs, libphonenumber

After installing https://github.com/halt-hammerzeit/libphonenumber-js using npm and updating my systemjs.config.ts to include

```
map:{
    ...
    'libphonenumber-js': 'node_modules/libphonenumber-js'
},
packages: {
    ...
    'libphonenumber-js': {
        main: './custom.es6.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
},
```

and attempting to use

```
import { parse, format, asYouType } from 'libphonenumber-js';
```

in my @Directive, I'm stuck with

> Cannot find module 'libphonenumber-js'

How on earth am I supposed to wire this library into my app?

EDIT:
**Directory layout:**
websiteName
websiteName/index.html
websiteName/node_modules
websiteName/node_modules/libphonenumber-js
websiteName/app
websiteName/app/systemjs.config.ts

Index.html contains:

```
<script src="/app/systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
    System.import('app').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
</script>
```

systemjs.config.ts contains:

```
declare var System: any;
/**
* System configuration for Angular samples
* Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
*/
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: 'app',
            // other references
            'libphonenumber-js': 'npm:libphonenumber-js'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            // other references
            'libphonenumber-js': {
                main: './bundle/libphonenumber-js.min.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

Comment: Are you sure that filepath is right?  Where is the package served from relative to the component?

Comment: @chrispy seems correct based on the other entries in SystemJS. Is there any way to get SystemJS to barf up any path errors? It's silent when loading the index.html that uses the System object.

Comment: If SystemJS cannot find the src file as specified in the config then it should result in a `404` in the console.

Comment: @TeddySterne It should, but replacing the data with `node_modules/butt` and `main: './stink.js'` still doesn't throw a 404 anywhere during typescript transpilation or page load (and I've double checked no-one's installed an npm stinky butt package that might have been getting picked up)

Comment: Please post the file structure of your app including the location of the lib file you wish to serve and the location of your SystemJS config whether it be a separate file or hard-coded in you index.html file.

Comment: @TeddySterne Edit includes this information. I'm not sure which file in the libphonenumber-js installation should be referenced and https://github.com/halt-hammerzeit/libphonenumber-js/issues/15 doesn't give me much more information

Answer (score 1):

Your package configuration is incorrect. It needs to point at the source file for `libphonenumber-js`. Need to update the references to match your project structure.

Try this:

```js
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': './node_modules'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: 'app',
            // other references
            'libphonenumber-js': 'npm:libphonenumber-js'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            // other references
            'libphonenumber-js': {
                main: 'libphonenumber-js.min',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

Comment: In the /bundle dir? Should that dir be specified in the map object or the packages object?

Comment: It depends on how your files are being served. If you are just referencing the files straight from the `node_module` dir then you can use the map defined in your question. If you are bundling several files into one then you would change the `main` definition to point to the bundle file.

Comment: Unfortunately, my Directive .ts file is still whinging with "Cannot find module 'libphonenumber-js'"

Comment: No joy with `'../node_modules'`, the rest of the app was working with the previous path too.

Comment: My mistake the config is relative to the loading context, aka `index.html`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Still not liking that. This is at transpilation time rather than runtime, which leads me to believe that the library isn't exporting them in the format that the IDE and application require